# Primefaces RequestContext execute after redirect

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i would run a javascript code with primefaces requestcontext after i redirect to another xhtml.. but it not works.. here is the code:

```
    else if (whatToOpen.equals("connectacc")) {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("customermaindata.xhtml");
                        context.execute("PF('dlg5').show();");
}
```

The redirect works, but the execute not.. how could i solve this? :)
Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You realise that you're trying to show a dialog box, after you've issued a directive to redirect away from the current page? what would be the point of trying to show a dialog box on a page that's no longer visible?

Comment: when i click the button i'm not on the page where the dialog is.i redirect to that page after the button clicked where the dialog is.. :)

Comment: Then you're looking at it the wrong way; you should first redirect, and then show the popup using a `viewAction` or a preRenderView event listener